# Django migrations - AddField is actually removing it

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, psql, django-migrations

I have a django blog project, and recently made changes to my local environment and so am now manually migrating to my production server. I've managed to nearly complete this, however when in psql / postgres I use the command:

> \d posts_post

The foreign key field:

> "Category" ( models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True))

Is nowhere to be seen as per the terminal. I've made another migration file as such:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations, models
import mptt.fields
import django.utils.timezone
import mptt
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('posts', '0016_remove_post_category'),
            ]
    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
                model_name="Post",
                name = "Category",
                field =  models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True)
            ),
           ]
```

However when I run the migrate command it actually removes the field.

a) Why does the manager remove my field instead of adding it?

b) Why is it doing this despite apparently not existing in the first place?

Comment: Does your database already have this field? Did you check that

Comment: It should have, but when I run \d posts_post to see what fields are in the table, it doesn't show. Although actually - there is a category_id field - is that it? Is that because it's a foreign key and not actually a normal field?

Comment: If you see `category_id`, then it s FK mapping field. You can't see a foreign key as the same name as you have given. It will be suffixed with _id

Comment: Brilliant thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see category_id, then it's FK mapping field. You can't see a foreign key as the same name that you have given in your `models.py`. It will be suffixed with `_id` in database level.

But while you use django orm, you will be using only the field name that you have given in your `models.py`